# Does python zlib library support uuencode?

Tags: python, gzip, email-attachments, zlib, uuencode

My python code is trying to decompress a uuencoded file using the zlib library. Here is the code snippet:

```
self.decompress = zlib.decompressobj(wbits)
.
.
buf = self.fileobj.read(size)
.
.
uncompress = self.decompress.decompress(buf)
```

My current value for wbits is '-zlib.MAX_WBITS'. This throws an error:

```
Error -3 while decompressing: invalid literal/lengths set
```

I realize that the python zlib library supports:

```
RFC 1950 (zlib compressed format)
RFC 1951 (deflate compressed format)
RFC 1952 (gzip compressed format)
```

and the choice for wbits is to be:

```
to (de-)compress deflate format, use wbits = -zlib.MAX_WBITS
to (de-)compress zlib format, use wbits = zlib.MAX_WBITS
to (de-)compress gzip format, use wbits = zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16
```

So my questions are:

```
Where does a uuencoded file fall in this list?
Is it supported by zlib?
If yes, what should be the value for wbits?
If no, how do I proceed with this?
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried just decoding it instead?

Comment: FWIW, uuencoding doesn't compress data, it expands it. UUencoding turns 3 bytes of arbitrary binary data into 4 bytes from a set of 64 safe printable chars. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding .

Comment: I assume you're talking about a file that was compressed using a zlib-compatible compression method and then uuencoded. If so, decode it using `str` `.decode('uu')` method or the `uu` module, then unzip it using zlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick demo of how to compress with zlib and encode with uuencode, and then reverse the procedure.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import zlib

data = '''This is a short piece of test data
intended to test uuencoding and decoding
using the uu module, and compression and 
decompression using zlib.
'''

data = data * 5

# encode
enc = zlib.compress(data, 9).encode('uu')
print enc

# decode
dec = zlib.decompress(enc.decode('uu'))

#print `dec` 
print dec == data
```

**output**

```
begin 666 <data>
M>-KMCLL-A# ,1.^I8@I 5$,#(?822V C[%RV>CXY; %[19K+/,U(;ZKBN)+A
MU8[ +EP8]D&P!RA'3J+!2DP(Z[0UUF(DNB K@;B7U/Q&4?E:8#-J*P_/HMBV
;'^PNID]/]^6'^N^[RCRFZ?5Y??[P.0$_I03L

end

True
```

---

The code above will only work on Python 2. Python 3 makes a clear separation between text and bytes, and it doesn't support the encoding of bytes strings, or the decoding of text strings. So it can't use the simple uuencoding / uudecoding technique shown above.

Here's a new version that works on both Python2 and Python 3.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import zlib
import uu
from io import BytesIO

def zlib_uuencode(databytes, name='<data>'):
    ''' Compress databytes with zlib & uuencode the result '''
    inbuff = BytesIO(zlib.compress(databytes, 9))
    outbuff = BytesIO()
    uu.encode(inbuff, outbuff, name=name)
    return outbuff.getvalue()

def zlib_uudecode(databytes):
    ''' uudecode databytes and decompress the result with zlib '''
    inbuff = BytesIO(databytes)
    outbuff = BytesIO()
    uu.decode(inbuff, outbuff)
    return zlib.decompress(outbuff.getvalue())

# Test

# Some plain text data
data = '''This is a short piece of test data
intended to test uuencoding and decoding
using the uu module, and compression and 
decompression using zlib.
'''

# Replicate the data so the compressor has something to compress
data = data * 5
#print(data)
print('Original length:', len(data))

# Convert the text to bytes & compress it.
databytes = data.encode()
enc = zlib_uuencode(databytes)
enc_text = enc.decode()
print(enc_text)
print('Encoded length:', len(enc_text))

# Decompress & verify that it's correct
dec = zlib_uudecode(enc)
print(dec == databytes)
```

**output**

```
Original length: 720
begin 666 <data>
M>-KMCLL-A# ,1.^I8@I 5$,#(?822V C[%RV>CXY; %[19K+/,U(;ZKBN)+A
MU8[ +EP8]D&P!RA'3J+!2DP(Z[0UUF(DNB K@;B7U/Q&4?E:8#-J*P_/HMBV
;'^PNID]/]^6'^N^[RCRFZ?5Y??[P.0$_I03L

end

Encoded length: 185
True
```

Please note that `zlib_uuencode` and `zlib_uuencode` work on `bytes` strings: you must pass them a `bytes` arg, and they return a `bytes` result.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with python3 (also not after adding parenthesis for print):  TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: @user44400 No, it's Python 2 only, I'm afraid. A slightly different approach is needed in Python 3, because Python 3 makes a clear distinction between text and bytes. I'll add a Python 3 version shortly.